# Is it possible to show an alert in specified activity of android App

Tags: android, sdk, android-activity

I am trying to build an SDK which has to show alert message on any given activity without adding any extra code in that particular activity.

Example: If we have an android app with 10 pages and if we say we need to show an alert on page6(activity with name) by simply adding an SDK invoked at Main Activity.

Is it possible? How can we do this without adding code in each of the activity?

Update: Basically want to identify the number of activities in the App and show alert message on any of the given activity without adding single line of code in the activity but we can add the code in MainActivity.

Comment: create one utility class. create method for show alert in this class.

Comment: Below is simple code which you can use it every where.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps

1) Create **Utility.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;


public class Utility {
    public interface AlertNeutral {

        public abstract void NeutralMathod(DialogInterface dialog, int id);

    }

    public static void showAlert(final Context mContext, final String title, final String msg, final String buttonCaption, final boolean isCancelable, final AlertNeutral target) {
        try {

            ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

                    int imageResource = android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning;
                    Drawable image = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

                    builder.setTitle(title).setMessage(msg).setIcon(image).setCancelable(false).setNeutralButton(buttonCaption, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            target.NeutralMathod(dialog, id);
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.setCancelable(isCancelable);
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

2) Call the above function from Any Activity you want.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.demo.Utility.AlertNeutral;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Utility.showAlert(this,"Demo Alert Title", "Demo Alert Message", "Demo Button Ok", true, new AlertNeutral() {

            @Override
            public void NeutralMathod(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: This is not something expected, Your solution asks the developer to change all the activities where we want to show the alert.The idea is, if you see my example in the question,we want to show alert in 6th activity without adding single line of code in 6th activity(but you are allowed to adding code in MainActivity).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a class and create the alert message there and then call it whenever you want to. I suppose when you say alert you mean alert dialog.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;

public CustomAlertDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        buildDialog();
    }
private void buildDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setView(popupView);
        alertDialog = builder.create();
            //here create your dialog
}

public void showDialog () {
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

and then all you have to do is initiate the `CustomAlertDialog` and call the `showDialog`
 method. If you want to dismiss it somehow do a dismissDialog method.

Answer (score 0):

Create an BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

public void showDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            BaseActivity.this);
    // add extra parameters

    alertDialog.show();

}
}
```

and extend every activity with BaseActivity

```
class your_activity extends BaseActivity{

 // here you can use showDialog

}
```

Comment: This is not something expecting, Your solution asks the developer to change all the activities where we want to show the alert.As an SDK distributor, I don't want to ask the developer to change all their activities to extend from BaseActivity. The idea is,there should be one line of invocation in MainActivity.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Alert {

public static void showAlert(Context context, String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: You can call it from every activity by passing title and message for alert.